# Show / hide page content on click

Tags: jquery, web

I've spent most of the day attempting to use multiple suggested solutions to this problem and none have either worked or been exactly what I was after.

I'm simply after a method to hide text content on page load and make it visible when the user clicks on the associated link, hiding again when the same link is clicked again or a separate link is clicked.

- An "about" link displays content about the project.
- A "contact" link displays content information.
- And so on.

The content is divided into relevant div's:

```
<div class="about">
This project is about X, Y & Z
</div>

<div class="contact">
Please contact me at@at.com
</div>
```

All content is loaded to a single, central content container on the site.

Thank you.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/hide/

Comment: How does your link html look like?

Comment: Please show the *javascript that you have tried* so we can help you understand where you went wrong - you won't learn if we simply code it for you.

Comment: @ahren Yes I'm mindful of this, however at the time of posting I had deleted all but the most recent attempt. I'll ensure future postings include all attempted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="" data-box="about">About</a>
<a href="" data-box="contact">Contact</a>

<div class="box about">
This project is about X, Y & Z
</div>

<div class="box contact">
Please contact me at@at.com
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();

        // hide everything
       $('.box').not(
           // except the corresponding box
           $('.box.'+$(this).data('box')+':hidden').fadeIn()
       ).fadeOut(); 
    });
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/tgeNm/

Comment: I'm using your code but it's not appearing...Does the About <a href=""> need to point to anything? An #about anchor or something? I've formatted the .box div for ideal placement and set its z-index to 9999. The about div only contains text formatting.

Comment: @Hohohobo yes the links need to have a `data-box=""` attribute with the name (class) of the box.

Comment: Something is still eluding me.. I had already included the data-box="" tag from your original answer: <a href="" data-box="test">ABOUT</a> like so, and the About content div is like so: <div class="box about"> but no content is loading on clicking the About link.

Comment: @Hohohobo it has to be the same as the box class so if you have `data-box="text"` it tries to open a box with `class="box test"`. To open the `about` box you need `data-box="about"`.

Comment: Argh, sorry, that was when I was troubleshooting. I've reinstated data-box="about" into the link - as it was originally - and I'm still not getting it. My formatting is fine. When I don't hide the .about div it displays correctly. Should I make a new question thread and display the code as it currently stands?

Comment: @Hohohobo you can just edit your current question and add your code there, or create a jsfiddle and post it here and i'll have a look.

Comment: @Hohohobo there was an error in the css file (missing `}` on `#background`) and the text-color of your about and contact boxes was white. so they were invisible. try this: http://jsfiddle.net/2udLs/3/

Comment: Also make sure the $('a').click block is inside the jquery ready function on your site: `$(function() {` (jsfiddle does this automatically)

Comment: The missing #background bracket and the white text on jsfiddle were issues when copying/pasting the code from my editor. I think the problem may be with the jquery ready function, but I don't fully understand what I need to write. .ready($('a').click { ? Would it be possible for you to please edit your post with that additional code?

Comment: @Hohohobo just put the .click inside the $(function(){ ... }); I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS

```
.toHide{
   display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="about toHide">
This project is about X, Y & Z
</div>

<div class="contact toHide">
Please contact me at@at.com
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#about').click(function (e) { //in this case I assume you have a element with ID `about` that will trigger the div with that class to show up
    $('.toHide').hide();
    $('.' + this.id).show();
});
```

Ingredients:

- a new class to hide all the divs
- jQuery hide() & show()
- a click() event handler

Answer (score -1):

This is easily accomplished with jquery.  Add a class to show what fields are expandable/collapsible:

```
<div class="about expandable">
This project is about X, Y & Z
</div>

<div class="contact expandable">
Please contact me at@at.com
</div>
```

In your javascript file:

```
$('.expandable').click(function(e){
    $(this).toggle();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Jquery accordion can be help you http://jqueryui.com/accordion/